# Problem with GFF parser by BCBio

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to parse a GFF file using the BCBio GFF parser and I get the following error. Can anybody help me in resolving this problem?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "gff_parse.py", line 6, in <module>
    for rec in GFF.parse(in_handle):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BCBio/GFF/GFFParser.py", line 709, in parse
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BCBio/GFF/GFFParser.py", line 299, in parse_in_parts
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BCBio/GFF/GFFParser.py", line 320, in parse_simple
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BCBio/GFF/GFFParser.py", line 603, in _gff_process
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BCBio/GFF/GFFParser.py", line 634, in _lines_to_out_info
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/BCBio/GFF/GFFParser.py", line 183, in _gff_line_map
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'New Start'
```

Here is my code:

```
from BCBio import GFF    
in_file = "infile.gff"    
in_handle = open(in_file)
for rec in GFF.parse(in_handle):
    print rec
in_handle.close()
```

Thanks 
Tulika

Answer (score 2):

How did you generate the GFF file? It appears to contain at least one invalid line. The fourth column should contain integers for the start coordinate of a feature; the error message indicates it contains the value 'New Start' instead.

The [GFF3 specification page](http://www.sequenceontology.org/gff3.shtml) has some examples of valid GFF, and the [online validator](http://modencode.oicr.on.ca/cgi-bin/validate_gff3_online) can help with debugging formatting issues like this.